# Is it possible to use class properties as types in Dart as it in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dart, types

In Typescript

```
class Apple {
 constructor (public color: string, public size: number)
}
```

So, it will be possible to use types of above class this way:

```
const growTo =(color: Apple['color'], size:Apple['size']) => console.log('growing..')
```

Not the best example, but important the meaning of it.

In other words, in Typescript, it is possible to use class property type to point type somewhere in another class, function and it creates really easy readable code.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any mentions of how to do that in Dart.
The question - is it possible to do something like that in Dart?

**Update 1 - example of purpose:**

First of all, I have to apologize for my English, it is not my native language.

**Goal:**
We have Tasks List and we want to convert them into Map.

Dart implementation will be looks like that:

```
class Task{
  int id;
  String name;
  Task({this.id,this.name});
}


void main() {

  List<Task> tasks = [Task(id: 0, name: 'todo1'), Task(id:1, name: 'todo2')];
  Map<int, Task> tasksMap = { for (Task task in tasks) task.id: task };
  
}
```

Problem 1.
What value is used as a key for Map?
It is an id, but, to know it, we need to look up methods of how the map will be populating.

Problem 2.
What if one day we decided to change the type for id in Task class from int to String?
In this case, we will need to change any type errors, which occurs, where we used type int as id type.

How it is solved with Typescript:

```
class Task{
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string){};
}
    
const tasks: Task[] = [new Task(0,'todo1'), new Task(1, 'todo2')]
const tasksMap: Map<Task['id'], Task> = new Map(tasks.map(task=> [task.id, task]))
```

**Explanation:**

Task['id'] refers to the current type in class Task, and it is for now number.
If we change type in class to string, then the Map key will automatically follow to changes and will be string too.

Problem 1 - solved.
We always know what we used for the key.

Problem 2 - solved.
If we change the type of Task.id then all types will be changed.

Comment: "creates really easy readable code"... I am not a TypeScript developer, so that might explain my confusion, but I have no idea what is going on in your example. Can you give a better description or a link to an article about this concept?

Comment: @julemand101  Please see paragraph Update 1 - example of purpose, hope it will be more understandable. Unfortunately I cannot find an official documentation for Typescript case right now, but if I find it I will add this information to the question.

Comment: Ok, but instead of `Map<int, Task> tasksMap = { for (Task task in tasks) task.id: task };`  you could have done: `var tasksMap = { for (Task task in tasks) task.id: task };`. This would let Dart automatically set the type of the variable based on the types from `task`. So if you later changes the type it will also happen here without any changes.

Comment: @julemand101 thank you! I just realized after experimenting and googling, that 'var' in dart is a way more typesafe than var in js/ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Dart 2.13 there is a solution to solve this problem using typedefs:

```dart
typedef AppleColor = String;
    
class Apple {
  final AppleColor color;
  const Apple ({required this.color});
}
    
void growTo(AppleColor color) => print('growing $color..');
```

Comment: That only solves the problem if you have access to the original class and can introduce a name for the type. It doesn't work for an arbitrary class that someone else has written.

Comment: @lrn yes, in that case as workaround you can extend class and override the field, or you can make extension with getter with required type.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Dart does not let you refer to types in any other way that:

- A literal type (`int`, `List<String>`, `int Function(int)`)
- A type variable (`T`)
- A typedef name (`F` where `typedef F = some Function(type);`)